# Когда и какие знаки препинания ставятся внутри закрывающих кавычек, а какие за ними?

Tags: прямая-речь

Прошу, скажите, какой вариант правильный

1. "Стыдно мне не знать русского языка" – сказала моя совесть.
2. "Стыдно мне не знать русского языка," – сказала моя совесть.
3. "Стыдно мне не знать русского языка", – сказала моя совесть.

Comment: Третий вариант.

Comment: Совесть сказала кому? Себе?

Comment: @Денис Федоров  Ваша совесть может сказать только одно: "Стыдно  ТЕБЕ [ВАМ] не знать русский язык!"  Кому стыдно-то: ВАМ или совести?

Comment: Римма, Вы ясно перемудрили с пониманием.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова после @ ники пишите без пробела.

Comment: @ДенисФедоров два ваших вопроса по сути повторяют друг друга, и по правилам проекта один из них должен быть закрыт. Так как на второй уже имеются ответы, оставлен именно он. Если вы с этим не согласны, могу сделать наоборот. С уважением, модератор

Comment: @Morkovkin Не обращала внимания на такой нюанс. "ДенисФедоров" - так? Благодарю. А я-то, бестолковая, никак не могла понять: КУДА имя у Галины Аванесовой девается? Пришлось извиняться.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, это "фишка" движка.

Comment: @МаркИз, Это не дубликат, а как бы вторая часть вопроса. Здесь прямая речь предшествует словам автора, и нужна запятая.